# PRXPARSE REGEX not returning all desired matches in this test data step

Tags: regex, sas

I am debugging a much bigger, complicated regex I have that is not behaving as expected by building a small scale one to understand where my issues are better. The purpose of this test regex is to detect US states on a case insensitive basis within a test dataset I have built. The code is here:

```
data countries;
do i = 1 to 10;
output;
end;
run;

data countries;
set countries;
if i = 1 then state = 'CALIFORNIA';
if i = 2 then state = 'alabama';
if i = 3 then state = 'New York';
if i = 4 then state = 'OHIO';
if i = 5 then state = 'ohio';
if i = 6 then state = 'FLORIDA';
if i = 7 then state = 'georgia';
if i = 8 then state = 'TEXAS';
if i = 9 then state = 'Kansas';
if i = 10 then state = 'MAINE';
run;

data countries;
set countries;
prx_1 = (prxparse("/^(?i:california|new\s+york|maine)$/"));
prx_valid_addr_1 = (prxmatch(prx_1, compress(state))) ;
run;
```

The problem I am having with this is that it is not detecting New York within my data. The regex looks correct for that string to me. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: @vks hi, thanks for replying. this has not worked either unfortunately.

Comment: But the regex you're using does find `CALIFORNIA` and `MAINE`, right?

Comment: What does `compress(state)` do? does it join them in to one string? in that case remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: Does `prx_1 = (prxparse("/^(?i:california|new\s*york|maine)$/"));` work?

Comment: FYI: `Compress`: [`Returns a character string with specified characters removed from the original string`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm)

Comment: thanks for the replies all...the regex i have written works fine, it was that i needed to use 'strip' instead of 'compress'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `*` instead of a `+`. Compress with no arguments [returns the original string with all spaces removed](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/n0fcshr0ir3h73n1b845c4aq58hz.htm#n1bjfb2ef1xuz9n1235oyjq1iqkm). Then, the `+` instead of `*` as a space multiplier requires at least one space to be present at that position. So when compress removes the space the match fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `strip()` instead of `compress()`.

Documentation for [strip](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0xk6tl87f4b4qn1sp1ywen1ntan.htm) and for [compress](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0fcshr0ir3h73n1b845c4aq58hz.htm).

As noted by @kums in the comments, `compress()`

> [r]eturns a character string with specified characters removed from
>   the original string.